# I need the GUID for an INALayer object

Tags: network-analyst

I've been searching the documentation for the GUID for a Network Analysis Layer object.  For example, "E156D7E5-22AF-11D3-9F99-00C04F6BC78E" is the Interface identifier for an IGeoFeatureLayer.

Answer (score 5):

The GUID for INALayer is 667B776B-5905-4450-9C94-18B214ECE8FB. This can be found in the registry by performing a search in RegEdit or programatically:

```
typeof(INALayer).GUID.ToString()
```